# Can this while loop be made cleaner

Tags: java, android, performance, coding-style

Is there a way to make the following while loop a little more optimized. What bugs me in particular is the fact that I have to repeat code (closing buffers and returning a value) both inside and outside the if condition and I wanted to get opinions on whether there might be a better /more performance-oriented way to handle such code.

```
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
  // Get a random line number
  if (currLine == lineToFetch) {
    quote = line;
    Log.v("LINE", line);
    randomQuote.close();
    buf.close();
    return quote;
  } else {
    currLine++;
  }
}

randomQuote.close();
buf.close();
return quote;
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your method. Also, may be more appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think so, but in java there is nothing impossible so try =0

Comment: This question appears to belong on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks I'll re-post on code review. I didn't know it existed! Thanks.

Comment: New location for the post - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38513/can-this-while-loop-be-made-cleaner

Answer (score 4):

Since you call `close()` and you return `quote` whatever you found or not your line, you can make it more nice :

```
 while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null && currLine != lineToFetch) {
        currLine++;
 }
 if (currLine == lineToFetch){
      quote = line;
 }
 randomQuote.close();
 buf.close();
 return quote;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it with a `finally` block like so -

```
try {
    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        // Get a random line number
        if (currLine == lineToFetch) {
            quote = line;
            Log.v("LINE", line);    
            break;
        } else {
            currLine++;
        }
    }
} finally {
    randomQuote.close();
    buf.close();
}
return quote;
```

Comment: Since `randomQuote` and `buf` seem to implement `AutoCloseable`, I'd prefer try-with-resources instead of try-finally.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `break` to exit your loop, and then rely on the cleanup code at the end of the function:

```
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    // Get a random line number
    if (currLine == lineToFetch) {
        quote = line;
        Log.v("LINE", line);
        break;
    } else
        currLine++;
}
randomQuote.close();
buf.close();
return quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just exit the while loop when you've found the quote:

```
    foundQuote = false;

    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null && !foundQuote ) {
      // Get a random line number
      if (currLine == lineToFetch) {
        quote = line;
        foundQuote = true;
    } else
        currLine++;
    }

    randomQuote.close();
    buf.close();
    return quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just read lines until you've found the one you want. If you've found it, then line will be non-null.

```
while ((line = buf.readline()) != null && curLine < lineToFetch)
    curLine++;

// make sure we've found the line
if ( line != null) {
    quote = line;
    Log.v("LINE", line );
}

randomQote.close();
buf.close();
return quote;
```